# Restriction rules - which HTML markup tag is used?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, html, web

I am currently testing the new Restriction Rules feature. I have a custom object called Construction and as I am creating the new Restriction Rule and adding a record criteria field, it happens that a value that I've added before into a search box is suggested for me. Because of this, I can not see an item in the list of fields - the value appears just under the search box and covers the top of the list.

My question is - is this clearly a bug and if it is so, which HTML element (or attribute) in the search box component allows users to be suggested values that were previously put into a similar box? I tried looking it up on w3c ([w3c input](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)) but I haven't found anything.

[image: Example]

Comment: This could be by design or the developer might have left to turn off the autocomplete on the input. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

Comment: @SachinHooda Brilliant! That's it, thanks.